# How to Change Settings Navigation Menu Item Text in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I know it sounds really simple but I'm new to WinUI 3 and I'm learning it. As you know there isn't really much documents and community about it and it's really hard to find your answers.
anyway, I want to change the text of this:

[image]

the page code is the default shellpage.xaml made by Template Studio for WinUI 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
<NavigationView Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded"/>
```

```cs
private void NavigationView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not NavigationView navigationView ||
        navigationView.SettingsItem is not NavigationViewItem settingsNavigationViewItem)
    {
        return;
    }

    settingsNavigationViewItem.Content = "Awesome Settings";
}
```

Comment: Thank You, That Worked perfectly. Can you edit your answer and explain a little so I can understand and not to come back and look for your answer every time? or maybe a link to read about it? thanks again.